# JSON, XML or something else for a real time high data TCP connection?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-protocols

I'm writing a game in C# and I am just about to start on communications between server and client. I will need to send a 20x20x20 array of chunks from the game map whenever the client requests it, updates of player movement and actions, updates to chunks which the client has loaded in, send movement and actions data to the server and a bunch of other things.
All of this of course has to be done with as high performance as I can squeeze out of it, but I don't want to write my own packet generator/parser when .NET has neat JSON and XML serialization.
Should I use JSON, XML or something entirely different for this connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider protobuf-net:

https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

I did some prototyping with this and was quite pleased with the results.

Comment: On the page it says it's compatible with .NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5. My project is 4.5, will this be fine?